# Does Makefile "-B" get passed to "child" Makefiles

Tags: unix, makefile

If I have a Makefile that calls another Makefile:

```
my_target:
    $(MAKE) -C path/to/Makefile all
```

And I run:

```
make -B my_target
```

Will the `-B` flag be passed to the other Makefile when it is called `$(MAKE) -C path/to/Makefile all`?

Comment: Yes, it will be. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion).

Comment: You can also easily see this for yourself; use something like `echo 'all: ; +echo MAKEFLAGS=$$MAKEFLAGS' | make -f- -B` and you'll see it prints `MAKEFLAGS=B` which shows that sub-makes will inherit this option.